# Parse SDK: Error in PFQueryTableViewController.h

Tags: ios, parse-platform, tableview

I downloaded the latest Parse SDK for iOS.  In my project I created a new UITableViewController class and subclassed PFQueryTableViewController.  When trying to run the project I get 26 issues in the PFQueryTableViewController.h.   If I remove my controller the error goes away.  Any ideas why this is happening.  Thanks in Advance.

[image: The error I get.]

Comment: Have you imported ParseUI in the header file?

Comment: Yes of course..Have tried it again, but it still does not work

Comment: What else have you imported? Try UIKit or Foundation...

Comment: I have tried UIKit and Foundation but it still does not work. What could I try?